# Can I use Azure Active Directory For Testing

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am adding active directory login to a internal application but wanted to test it in an isolated environment, does Azure Active Directory offer any way I can create a 'test' AD to authenticate the user via LDAP to provide me with this isolated environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Active Directory is a multi-tenant service that provides identity and access management for cloud applications.  It's not the same as Server Active Directory nor is it an instance of Windows Server AD running in a Virtual Machine in Azure.

So, to answer your question - no.

If you want an instance of Server AD to test LDAP queries on you could spin one up in a Virtual Machine.  You will need to put it in a Virtual Network.  Also, create an instance of a Virtual Machine to run your application on that you want to test.

This tutorial should take care of it for you.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/